# Definite integral $\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx$. Use trig substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral:

> $$\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+1}\, dx$$

but I have gotten stuck. Here's the work I have done already:
[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here. Using a trig identity doesn't seem like it would work. Integration by parts doesn't work (at least I think so)

Any ideas on what I should do next?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed to use hyperbolic sub? hyperbolic sine  etc?

Comment: You can use hyperbolic functions instead. Alternatively, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: I do not know how to use hyperbolic sub or sine. I have not learned those yet. Which is weird (maybe) since I have taken calc 1 already.

Comment: Do you have a course named differential geometry?

Comment: Well use this $$\int\sec^3t dt=\int\dfrac{\cos t}{(1-\sin^2t)^2}dt$$

Comment: Analytic Geometry-Calculus 2. I have taken Analytic Geometry-Calculus 1 already. I have never learned anything about hyperbolic sine or sub. Maybe it's just my uni, I do remember seeing it in the textbook, but we never got into it.

Comment: I can do it without any subsitution but it is a bit long. Is it ok?

Comment: That would be ok, but MyGlasses has made an answer that may help me get through the problem. Let me see if I can get through it first. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any problem in using, $$\int \sec^3 x \  dx = \dfrac{\ln|\sec x + \tan x|}{2} + \dfrac{\sec x \tan x}{2} + C$$ ?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269837/different-ways-to-solve-int-01-sqrt1x2-dx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:)**

Since $\cosh^2u=\sinh^2u+1$ so let $x=\sinh u$.

---

It's better to do this
$$\int\sec^3t dt=\int\dfrac{\cos t}{(1-\sin^2t)^2}dt$$

---

**Edit:**
\begin{align}
I  
&= \int\sec^3t dt \\
&= \int\dfrac{1}{\cos^3t} dt \\
&= \int\dfrac{\cos t}{\cos^4t} dt \\
&= \int\dfrac{\cos t}{(1-\sin^2t)^2}dt
\end{align}
with substitution $\sin t=u$:
$$I=\int\dfrac{du}{(1-u^2)^2}$$
with fraction decomposition
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(1-u^2)^2} 
&= \dfrac{A}{1-u}+\dfrac{B}{1+u}+\dfrac{C}{(1-u)^2}+\dfrac{D}{(1+u)^2} \\
&= \dfrac{(A+B+C+D)+(A-B+2C-2D)u+(-A-B+C+D)u^2+(-A+B)u^3}{(1-u^2)^2}
\end{align}
equivalency of coefficients in numerator shows
\begin{cases}
A+B+C+D=1,\\
A-B+2C-2D=0,\\
-A-B+C+D=0,\\
-A+B=0.
\end{cases}
so $A=B=C=D=\dfrac14$ and thus with $u=\sin t$
\begin{align}
I  
&= \dfrac14\int\left(\dfrac{1}{1-u}+\dfrac{1}{1+u}+\dfrac{1}{(1-u)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(1+u)^2}\right)du \\
&= \dfrac14\left(-\ln(1-u)+\ln(1+u)+\dfrac{1}{1-u}-\dfrac{1}{1+u}\right)+C \\
&= \dfrac14\left(\ln\dfrac{1+u}{1-u}+\dfrac{2u}{1-u^2}\right)+C \\
&= \dfrac14\left(\ln\dfrac{1+\sin t}{1-\sin t}+\dfrac{2\sin t}{1-\sin^2t}\right)+C \\
\end{align}
substitution $\sin^2t=\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ gives us
$$\color{blue}{\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\dfrac12\left(\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+x\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)+C}$$

Comment: Is that a formula I'm supposed to know? How did you get that?

Comment: $$\int\sec^3t dt=\int\dfrac{1}{\cos^3t} dt=\int\dfrac{\cos t}{\cos^4t} dt=\int\dfrac{\cos t}{(1-\sin^2t)^2}dt$$

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm supposed to _really_ mess with it to get it into the correct form. This is going to take some ingenuity.

Comment: This stuff is so hard! Ok, if I make u = sin(t), then du = cos(t)dt, correct? so now I end up with integrate( 1/(1-u^2)^2 ). Should I then make a u-substitution where u = 1-u^2? And go from there? Sorry about the formatting, where can I see how to do that? EDIT: No a u-sub wouldn't work. I guess I'm stuck, yet again.

Comment: After that do $\dfrac{A}{1-u}+\dfrac{B}{1+u}+\dfrac{C}{(1-u)^2}+\dfrac{D}{(1+u)^2}$ hard method but elementary!

Comment: Ah ha! I forgot about decomposition! Even though that was the last thing I learned, I still forgot it. Thank you. Let me see If I can get through the rest of this.

Comment: MyGlasses, can I ask something of you? Would you be able to write out a full solution to this problem? I am having a hard time connecting all of this information together. It is taking everything I just learned and cramming it into one question. I would be very grateful since I have I been trying to solve this for over an hour, and I'm getting to the point where it is hard to put this stuff into the right light. Thank you.

Comment: Of course. I'm free.

Comment: Thank you! If you put it as an answer to this question I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: The substitution $u=\tan\frac{t}{2}$ also works. [Read more about tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Comment: @DevHeavy Done! No mark need! Just learning ;)

Comment: @MyGlasses You made a mistake. It should be $\int \frac{du}{(1-u^2)^2}$. But then you need partial fractions for $\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses There we go! It all makes sense now! Just one question, would C = -1/4 ? I really can't explain how I got that, and I'm sure you are the one that is right. Just want to make sure.

Comment: @DevHeavy No. check again!

Comment: @MyGlasses you're right! I'm sorry, to have made you check it again. Just want to say, you're the best person on these forums! I have literally been working on this for almost two hours! But thanks to you my hell has come to an end. This won't be the last of me though, I'm sure I will be back with more questions for different problems. Also, thanks, user236182.

Comment: Thanks! You'r welcome! :)

Comment: You forgot $+C$. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

**hint**

Put $$x=\sinh (t) $$
and remember that:

$$\cosh^2 (t)-\sinh^2 (t)=1$$
$$dx=\cosh (t)dt $$

$$\cosh^2 (t)=\frac {1+\cosh (2t)}{2} $$

Comment: Isn't the last line just for cos(t), not cosh(t) ?

Comment: @valer the same formula is true for both.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** Old solution didn't work, this should work.

---

Your original thought was correct:
$$\begin{align}
&\int\sec^3 \theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta\\
=& \int(1+\tan^2\theta)\sec \theta \ \mathrm{d}\theta\\
=& \int \sec \theta \ \mathrm{d}\theta+ \int\sec \theta \tan^2 \theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}$$ Now, the first integral can be solved by multiplying through by $\frac{\tan \theta + \sec \theta}{\tan \theta + \sec \theta}$, and we integrate the second by parts. Let $\mathrm{d} v = \sec \theta \tan \theta\ \mathrm{d} \theta$, $u =\tan \theta$, so $v = \sec \theta$ and $\mathrm{d} u = \sec^2 \theta\ \mathrm{d} \theta$. 
Then, 
$$ \int \sec \theta  \tan^2 \theta \ \mathrm{d} \theta = \tan \theta \sec \theta  - \int \sec^3 \theta \ \mathrm{d} \theta$$

Putting it together, we have that $$\int \sec^3 \theta \ \mathrm{d} \theta = \tan \theta \sec \theta + \int \sec \theta \ \mathrm{d} \theta\ - \int \sec^3 \theta\ \mathrm{d} \theta$$
$$2\int \sec^3 \theta \ \mathrm{d} \theta = \tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec \theta\ \mathrm{d} \theta$$
You should be able to get it from here.
Notice that you forgot to change your bounds when letting $x = \tan \theta$.

Comment: I don't see how $u=\tan \theta$ directly solves $\int \sec\theta\tan^2 \theta\, d\theta$. $$\int \sec\theta\tan^2 \theta\, d\theta=\int\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^3 \theta}\, d\theta=$$

$$=\int u\sin\theta\, du$$

Comment: You're completely right, sorry, integrating $\sec^3 \theta$ directly would be easier. I had mixed it up with $\sec^2 \theta \tan \theta$

Comment: To solve $\int \sec \theta\, d\theta$, you can also use the substitutions $u=\sin \theta$, $u=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$. [Read about tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the substitution $x=\sinh u$, so $dx=\cosh u du$. This will give:
$$ \begin{align}
&\int_0^{\ln{1+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sinh^2u +1} \cdot \cosh u \ du \\
&\int_0^{\ln{1+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\cosh^2u} \cdot \cosh u \ du \\
&\int_0^{\ln{1+\sqrt{2}}} \cosh^2u \ du
\end{align}$$
Hope you can take it on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Time for some light artillery

$$Let \ I=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+1} \ dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx=\int_{0}^{1}x*\frac{{x}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx=\int_{0}^{1}x*({\sqrt{x^2+1}})'\ dx+ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})|_{0}^{1}=parts=x*({\sqrt{x^2+1}})|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+1} \ dx (<-I)+ln(1+\sqrt{2})=>I=\sqrt{2}-I+ln(1+\sqrt{2})=>2I=\sqrt{2}+ln(1+\sqrt{2})=>I=\frac{1}{2}[\sqrt{2}+ln(1+\sqrt{2})]  $$

Comment: Please brush up on [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)—particularly the use of `align`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a trigonometry substitution. Integrate by parts. Let $a\in\mathbb R$. I'm using $a^2$ instead of $a$ here because $x=a\tan t$, $x=a\cot t$ seem like possible substitutions. You've already tried $x=\tan \theta$ for your problem. At least one answer has shown how it can solve the problem.

$$I:=\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\, dx$$

$:=$ means "equal by definition".

$$\int u\, dv=uv-\int v\, du$$

$$u=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$$

$$du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\, dx$$

$$dv=dx, v=x$$

$$\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\, dx=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-$$

$$-\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\, dx=$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int \frac{(x^2+a^2)-a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\, dx=$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\, dx +$$

$$+a^2\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-I+$$

$$+a^2\int \frac{d(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})}{x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-I+$$

$$+a^2\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}|$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2}(x\sqrt{x^2+a^2})+$$

$$+\frac{1}{2}(a^2\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}|)+C$$

In the same way you could prove $$\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2}\, dx=\frac{1}{2}(x\sqrt{x^2-a^2})-$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}(a^2\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|)+C$$

We have

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\, dx=\frac{1}{2}(1\sqrt{1^2+a^2})+$$

$$+\frac{1}{2}(a^2\ln|1+\sqrt{1^2+a^2}|)-\frac{1}{2}(0\sqrt{0^2+a^2})-$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}(a^2\ln|0+\sqrt{0^2+a^2}|)$$

You used the substitution $x=\tan\theta$. You get $\int_0^1 \sec^3 \theta\, d\theta$. As one answer has shown, you can then use the substitution $u=\sin\theta$. Another possibility, which is always the case for any integral with all terms trigonometric terms $\sin x$, $\cos x$, etc., is the substitution $u=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$, which turns the integral into a rational one using $\sin\theta = \frac{2u}{u^2+1}$, $\cos \theta = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$, $du=\frac{(1+u^2)}{2}\, d\theta$, etc. Then try using partial fractions. [Read more about tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).